# MS SQL split old table into many to many relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

I have an old table with lots of columns that i want to split into 3 tables with many to many relation.

The old table have no identity column.

Old table:

```
CustomerNumber
FirstName
LastName
Address
Postal
City
....
```

New tables

Customer:

```
Id
Customernumber
Firstname
Lastname
... ect
```

Address:

```
Id
Address
Postal
City
... ect
```

CustomerAddress

```
Id
CustomerId
AddressId
```

Now how can I spilt the old tabel into the new ones using SQL?

I have tried with MERGE but that can't handle more than one table at the time. One option is using CURSOR, but I read that it is a bad idea, to use that or iteration, but for now that is the only solution I have found for this.

```
declare 
@CustomerId bigint,
@CustomerNumber float, 
@Status int,
@Address varchar(50),
@RoadNumber int,
@LastEdited datetime,

@AddressId bigint

declare my_cursor cursor
local static read_only forward_only
for
    select CustomerNumber, Address, Housenumber, Status, Date
    from [db1].dbo.OldCustomer k
    where 
        FIRMANR in (1, 40, 60, 80, 90, 120, 180, 400)

    open my_cursor
    fetch next from my_cursor into @CustomerNumber, @Address, @RoadNumber, @Status, @LastEdited
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    --if the customer already exists we get the identity
    if exists (select Id from [db2].dbo.Customers where CustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber)
        select @CustomerId = Id from [db2].dbo.Customers where CustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber

    --if the customer does not exit we need to insert and retrieve the new Identity value
    else
        begin
            -- insert the customer
            insert into [db2].dbo.Customers (CustomerNumber, [Status], LastEdited) values (@CustomerNumber, @Status, @LastEdited)
            set @CustomerId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        end

    -- get address if it already exists
    if exists (select Id from [db2].dbo.Addresses where Road = @Address and Roadnumber = @RoadNumber)
        select @AddressId = Id from [db2].dbo.Addresses where Road = @Address and Roadnumber = @RoadNumber
    else
        begin
            -- insert new addresses
            insert into [db2].dbo.Addresses (Road,Roadnumber) values (@Address, @RoadNumber)
            set @AddressId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        end

    -- insert customer => address reference if it does not exist
    if not exists (select Id from [db2].dbo.CustomerAddress where CustomerId = @CustomerId and AddressId = @AddressId)
        -- insert customer => address reference
        insert into [db2].dbo.CustomerAddress(CustomerId,AddressId) values (@CustomerId, @AddressId)


    fetch next from my_cursor into @CustomerNumber, @Address, @RoadNumber, @Status, @LastEdited
end

close my_cursor
deallocate my_cursor
```

Comment: Be very careful in your decision to move to a M:M relationship. That means different customers can "share" an address - something that is not possible now. In addition, there is no reason to add an ID column to CustomerAddress - it serves no obvious useful purpose. Do just blindly add an identity column to every table. Is it not true that the tuple (CustomerId, AddressId) uniquely identity each row in CustomerAddress? Then what is the purpose of Id?

Comment: When working with EntityFramework in .net Core 2 the ID in many to many relations is required at the moment, thats why it is in there. Regarding the many to many relation between customers and addresses, I plan to do this as i have other tables relating to addresses as well and this way I dont have to keep adresses more than one place.

Comment: Re the last point (and I think i covered this in my answer) it doesn't necessarily need a CustomerAddress table (because then you have to have SupplierAddress, BusinessAddress, ManufacturerAddress XyzAddress tables.. Consider not having the middleman table.. Each entity in your db that needs an address can just have an XuzAddressId column(s) in its own table, without the middleman

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this when I get back on job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be easiest to:

- Add a column to old customer called AddressId
- Populate it with unique IDs (you can reuse the Customer ID, or if its GUID, use NewID())
- Create new tables for address and customeraddress
- Insert part of the old customer data into each new table
- Drop columns from Customer that relate to address

---

```
--populate new Address table
INSERT INTO Address(id,col1,col2...)
SELECT AddressID, col1, col2... FROM Customer

--populate new CustomerAddress table
INSERT INTO CustomerAddress(CustomerId,AddressId)
SELECT Id, AddressID FROM Customer
```

With SQLS you can do this as a simple script, with a transaction if you want.. No need for stored procedures, cursors, merge etc..

Don't give CustomerAddress its own Id column; the primary key of CustomerAddress is the combination of CustomerId and AddressId; make a composite PK, not a separate one

Tbh, I'd probably not have a CustomerAddress table and instead just have a BillingAddressId, WorkAddressId, HomeAddressId, ShippingAddressId column in customer, but it's up to you how to manage this; If you have lots and variable types of addresses then sure, have a M:M breakdown, but if realistically your customers are only ever going to have up to 3 addresses etc, I'd stick with having a named column stating what the address was for, in customer

If you do go with a CustomerAddress table, consider adding a column declaring the type/reason for the address

Comment: Ok i will look into this approach this weekend and think more about using many to many